Opentelemetry not being recognised as an import
I'm trying to use opentelemetry traces within one of my function apps. This specific line is what I use to import the trace:
from opentelemetry import trace as trace_api
In any of my local developments, this is imported fine, however when I attempt to test how it works as an azure function app locally, through func start, I get this error:
...
from opentelemetry import trace as trace_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opentelemetry'
This error only occurs solely when using func start, and all necessary imports are listed in requirements.txt. Any suggestions?

Have you tried all of the steps in this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/opentelemetry-howto?tabs=app-insights&pivots=programming-language-python

Did you find the solution?? I'm facing same problem (from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.monitor')


from opentelemetry import trace as trace_api

To resolve this error, install azure-monitor-opentelemetry module.
I have configured opentelemetry in python azure function as below:
requirements.txt

Installed azure-monitor-opentelemetry module

azure-functions
azure-monitor-opentelemetry

functionapp.py:
import azure.functions as func
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace as trace_api

configure_azure_monitor(connection_string=os.environ["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"])
logging.getLogger("azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("azure.monitor.opentelemetry.exporter.export").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

Console output:

Able to run the function as expected:

(.venv) C:\Users\uname\pyfn>func start
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd0XXXX7ab209 (64-bit)       
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-16T05:57:23.582Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        http_trigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-16T05:57:28.632Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.       
[2024-08-16T05:57:34.860Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=91ffa574-fXXX9ccd-7effe6719d21)
[2024-08-16T05:57:34.973Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-16T05:57:35.086Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=91ffa574-fb3e-4XXXXeffe6719d21, Duration=253ms)


Thanks, I added the code from above however I'm still having issues. Now that I include the line to import azure-monitor-opentelemetry , I get this error:
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.monitor'
Clearly this means that it might not be a module error initially like I thought but perhaps something different : ( I have the modules downloaded and they are present in my requirements.txt. Any extra ideas?

Did you create and activate virtual environment?
